# Exception handling in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I am using spring integration to make parallel calls to two web services, I wanted to know how to handle the case when one service goes down for some reason. Say I get a timeout exception how do i handle it in spring integration.

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="wslService-request-b"
    method="webServiceCallB" output-channel="wslService-reply" ref="LITESWebServiceCall">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-delay="10"
        receive-timeout="40000" task-executor="wslServiceRequestExecutor" error-channel="ws-error-channel"/>
</int:service-activator>

<int:service-activator
input-channel="ws-error-channel"
ref="errorHandler" />
```

Comment: Seems like not enough info. You ask about parallel call, but show the sample about 'one message in 10 milliseconds after previous message was processed'. From other side your config looks good. And any Excpetions from that polling flow should be sended to the **ws-error-channel**. Can you shed more light for the issue?

Comment: See http://xpadro.blogspot.com.es/2013/11/how-error-handling-works-in-spring.html for information on error handling in Spring Integration.